# Multiple backreferences for multiple match in regular expression for Apache mod_rewrite

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, recursion

I need to know if it is possible, having a regular expression, used in a mod_rewrite, to match a non-predictable number of times a certain sequence and access the matches using a backreference to each of them.

An example avails more than many words:

sequence to match:

> 0102030405....

(sequence length= n*2, where n could be a number greater or equal to 1)

regular expression:

> ([0-9][0-9]+)

I would need to be able to get each of the n matches in the sequence, in order to use them in a mod_rewrite rule, that would give the following translations:

> /01.html => /01/index.html
>
> /0102.html => /01/02/index.html
>
> /010203.html => /01/02/03/index.html
>
> /01020304.html => /01/02/03/04/index.html
>
> ...

Would that be possible to get this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use these 2 rules for that:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+?/)?([0-9]{2})\.html$ /$1$2/index.html [L]

RewriteRule ^(.+?/)?([0-9]{2})([0-9]+.+?\.html)$ /$1$2/$3 [L]
```

Comment: Doesn't work. It clearly doesn't deal with this case:
/010203.html => /01/02/03/index.html

Comment: With above rules in place `/010203.html` is internally rewritten to `/01/02/03/index.html` which is **exactly as you wrote** in your question. Most likely you have some conflicting rules. If you want redirection then add `R` flag in 1st rule as: `RewriteRule ^(.+?/)?([0-9]{2})\.html$ /$1$2/index.html [L,R]`